# ruby combine hash related key

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to combine related key for example:

```
my_hash = {key_a: "value a", key_b: "value b", key_c: "value c"}
```

I want the result to be:

```
{ key:
  [
    { a: "value a" },
    { b: "value b" },
    { c: "value c" }
  ]
}
```

It can be easily do that by getting each key explicitly but the problem is, it can define dynamic key.

THE PROBLEM is `key_` is can be any, you can't determine what is after `key_`. It can be `key_r`, `key_w`, `key_z`

Comment: Use a matching function that will check or match the word key_ or, functions like include or use regex

Comment: Why are you using a version of Ruby on Rails that has been unmaintained for many years and has unfixed bugs and security vulnerabilities? Why are you using two versions of Ruby on Rails in the same project? What does this have to do with Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Seems like you want to split the key name by `_` and then group the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
my_hash = { key_a: "value a", key_b: "value b", key_c: "value c" }

my_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), result| 
  prefix, suffix = key.to_s.split('_').map(&:to_sym)
  result[prefix] ||= []; 
  result[prefix] << { suffix => value }
end
#=> { key: [{ a: "value a" }, { b: "value b" }, { c: "value c" }] }
```

And I would suggest changing the data structure a bit, because IMO it doesn't make sense that the nested hashes has only on key/value pair:

```
my_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), result| 
  prefix, suffix = key.to_s.split('_').map(&:to_sym)
  result[prefix] ||= {}; 
  result[prefix][suffix] = value
end
#=> { key: { a: "value a", b: "value b", c: "value c" } }
```

Comment: I agree with your argument about changing the data structure, but couldn't the same argument be made to simply return `{ a: "value a", b: "value b", c: "value c" }`?

Comment: I actually thought that there might be other prefixes than just `key` and therefore thought that the `key` nesting made kinda sense.

Answer (score 2):

If the `key` part is always the same, you can do:

```rb
{ key: my_hash.collect { |k, v| { k.to_s.sub('key_', '').to_sym => v } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
my_hash = {key_a: "value a", key_b: "value b", key_c: "value c"}
```

Code

```
new_hash = { key: [] }
my_hash.each_key do |key|
  if key.to_s.start_with?("key_")
    new_key = key.to_s.split("_")[1].to_sym
    new_hash[:key] << { new_key => my_hash[key] }
  end
end
p new_hash
```

Output:

```
{:key=>[{:a=>"value a"}, {:b=>"value b"}, {:c=>"value c"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some messiness here, namely, strings must be extracted from keys that are symbols, modified, then converted back to symbols. It is convenient to define helper methods to do that, in part so that they may be tested separately.

```
def key_prefix(key_sym)
  key_sym[/[^_]*/].to_sym
end
```

```
def key_suffix(key_sym)
  key_sym[/[^_]*\z/].to_sym
end
```

For example,

```
key_prefix(:key_ccc) #=> :key
key_suffix(:key_ccc) #=> :ccc
```

See [Symbol#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/Symbol.html#method-i-5B-5D).

---

Then we may write

```
my_hash = {key_a: "value a", key_b: "value b", key_ccc: "value c"}
```

```
{key_prefix(my_hash.first.first)=>my_hash.map {|k,v| { key_suffix(k)=>v}}}
  #=> {:key=>[{:a=>"value a"}, {:b=>"value b"}, {:ccc=>"value c"}]}
```

---

The regular expression `/[^_]*/` matches zero or more (`*`) characters (as many as possible) from the character class `[^_]`, the latter being comprised of all characters other than (`^`) the underscore. The regular expression `/[^_]*\z/` is the same except the match must be at the end of the string (`\z` is the end-of-string anchor).